# YUV video processing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, video-processing, yuv

I am using this function I got from the internet:

```
>>[Y,U,V]=yuv_import('test.yuv',[176 144],150,0)
```

I got this from: [Convert YUV CIF 4:2:0 video file to image files](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6318)

It prints out the Y, U and V components of the yuv file test.yuv. When I typed:

```
>>Y
```

It displayed:

```
Y = 

  Columns 1 through 5

    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]

............... 

  Columns 146 through 150

    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]    [144x176 double]
```

And..

```
>>size(Y)
```

displayed:

```
ans =

     1   150
```

Doing the same for U and V components also showed the same results.

And also..

```
>>Y(150)
```

displayed:

```
ans = 

    [144x176 double]
```

What I want is make an array for Y, U and V that has the dimensions [numberOfFrames height width] or [150 144 176]. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outputs are cell-arrays.

```
>> Y = cat(3, Y{:} );
```

should do the trick for you.

Comment: How can you convert it back to the original once you have [numberOfFrames height width]?

Comment: @mc8 what do you mean "original"? a cell array? an RGB? you can use `permute` to change from `[nFrames H W]` to `[H W nFrames]`. You can use `mat2cell` to convert back to cell array...

Comment: can you please give an example on how to use mat2cell using size [numberOfFrames height width] to size [1 numberOfFrames] or [1 150] like above?